# how to name a method in functional programming JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, naming-conventions, immutability

when we do not want to break the immutability of an object, we will create a copy of it each time we will call a mutator method like a setter method, or any method that will change any property in the object.
Now the question is really about naming conventions: since the setter is not mutating the object any longer, rather it creates a copy and returns a copy of the object, so what should we name it?
here is an example

```
   weatherData: function (obj) {
        let value_Copy = { ...obj }
        const getValue = () => value_Copy
        const setValue = (_value) => weatherData(_value) // this is not a mutator, it is just returns a copy with new arguments 
        return { getValue, setValue }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would give the new value a meaningful name of its own. Naturally you are performing an "update" operation on the original data for a purpose. My name for the new variable would describe why it was updated, because that will make the code more readable.

Compare

```js
const weatherToday = weatherData(someData)
const weatherTomorrow = weatherToday.setValue('temperature', 23)
```

with

```js
const weather = weatherData(someData)
const weather2 = weatherData.setValue('temperature', 23)
```

The former shows the reader what the new data is for. The second will very quickly become unreadable.

Comment: thanks a lot, it makes sense what you just mentioned. I have no idea why this question received some negative votes, it is a matter of writing cleaner code, that is all what this question about. thanks again for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Most functions need to include a setter function".

You also don't say what programming language you are working with.

In a pure functional approach, there is no such thing as a "setter", nor a "mutator". Those are generally object-oriented concepts.

If you are working in an object-oriented language, e.g. Java, and trying to work in a functional style, then you are likely to have a mix of object-oriented and functional styles, so I suppose the dividing line between the two would be up to you.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more concrete, thanks for the note. I think now it will make more sense

Comment: thanks for the feedback, when you want to design a model to be used in the application, even in a functional programming language, you need to provide some mutators e.g., change the property of an object. in the example above I used a setter to change the value of the temperature object. so I am looking for achieve OOP style in javascript but without mutating the original object to get both benifits from both styles, which has led to naming confusion I had. thanks again for the feedback